# Why wont my Binary Search Tree display more then 3 nodes?

Tags: java, stack, binary-search-tree, iterable

My Binary Search Tree cant seem to manage more then 3 nodes or be able to display them. I needed to add them iterably and display them using a stack in the assignment but am having trouble displaying the BST if it has more then 3 elements.

```
public boolean add(E b) {

    //if tree is empty
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node();
        root.setValue(b);
        count++;
        return true;
    } //if val is already in tree
    else if (b.compareTo(root.getValue()) == 0) {
        return false;
        //if left or right spot is free
    } else {
        while (root != null) {
            compareResult = root.value.compareTo(b);
            spot = root;
            if (compareResult < 0) {
                if (root.left != null) {
                    spot = spot.left;
                    count++;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Node n = new Node<>();
                    n.setValue(b);
                    spot.left = n;
                    count++;
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (compareResult > 0) {
                if (root.right != null) {
                    spot = spot.right;
                    count++;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    Node n = new Node<>();
                    n.setValue(b);
                    spot.right = n;
                    count++;
                    return true;

                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public void display() {
    //needs to use an iterator
    if (root == null) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    } else {
        Node CurrentNode;
        CurrentNode = root;
        while (!stack.isEmpty() || CurrentNode != null) {
            if (CurrentNode != null) {
                stack.push(CurrentNode);
                CurrentNode = CurrentNode.right;


            }
            else {
                Node m= stack.pop();
                System.out.println(m.value);
                CurrentNode = m.left;
            }

        }
    }
}

public int size() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(E t) {
    return ordering.compare(root,t);
}

@Override
public int compare(E t, E t1) {
    return t.compareTo(t1);
}
```

The Node class looks like this

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable> {

E value;
Node<E> left;
Node<E> right;

//constructor
public Node() {
    value = null;
    left = null;
    right = null;


}

public void setValue(E t) {
    value = t;
}

public void setLeft(Node<E> t) {
    left = t;

}

public void setRight(Node<E> t) {
    right = t;
}

public Node<E> getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public Node<E> getRight() {
        return right;
}

public E getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This is not a full answer, because I'm not going to do your homework for you.  But basically, your `add` method needs to be recursive.  As it is, it only adds things at the root of the node, or at the left child, or at the right child.  Much of your logic can be removed, because if the value you're inserting is _less than_ the value at the root, you can just call `add` again passing the node on the left.  And if it's _greater than_ the value at the root, you can just call `add` again passing the node on the right.  You are missing this recursive step.

Comment: How would I call it recursively? Most of the objects inside the BST are Node objects so I can't call add again. I can call Add only on an E which then I wouldn't know how to end the program.

Comment: You've got a couple of options.  You could put the `add` method in the `Node` class.  Then the `add` method in the `Tree` class would check whether a `Node` exists, and call `add` on that `Node` if it does.  Alternatively, you could make it so that `left` and `right` inside the `Node` class are actually trees, not just nodes.

Comment: I originally had it so that the node class has the add method in it, but my teacher said that the Node class should only contain a reference to the left and right. Other then that she gave instruction in class to do something similar to what I did in my add method, and said we shouldn't use recursion. I feel really stuck and the Node class is exactly how she instructed us to make it.

Comment: Your teacher said you shouldn't use recursion?  That's very strange.  Recursion is the right way to do it.  I guess you could use a giant loop that goes down the tree and exits when you find the parent of the right spot to add the node.  I can see that that's what you've tried to do, but your condition `while(root != null)` is wrong, because `root` will always be not null once you get to the `else` clause.

Comment: Now that I understand how you're trying to do this, I'll have a closer look at your code.

Comment: If you don't use recursion you will certainly need a stack.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of changes that you need to make.

After the `} else {` line in your `add` method, you should swap the next three lines around, to have

```
  spot = root;
  while (spot != null) {
        compareResult = spot.value.compareTo(b);
```

because `spot` is going to track its way down the tree while you iterate the loop.  But because you're currently using `root` instead of `spot`, you're always comparing values with the `root` node, instead of lower down nodes.

Also, remove `count++;` and `return true;` from after `spot = spot.left;` and `spot = spot.right;`, because in these cases, you haven't actually added anything to the tree, so you need to continue on through the loop.